# Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10

Tags: java, android, rx-java

My project is in Java , but when i tried to compile the project , it throws kotlin-related error that there are duplicate classes whereas i'm not really using any kotlin dependency or kotlin , any reason why this is happening Thank you .

- This is my build gradle ( for project )

[image]

- This is my build gradle ( for module )

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have problems using Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1
After updating 3 libraries:
in app/build.gradle I have updated:
From:

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'  
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'  
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
```

To:

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'  
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'  
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
```

I undo it and worked.

Comment: To update propertly to androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1 to must need update: the kotlin plugin and the compose version, also the must have a compatibility between them. You can check this documentation if u want to understand a little more: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

ADD in "build.gradle" implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0")) and Sync project.

After that REMOVE the above implementation "build.gradle" and Sync AGAIN.